# Pretty Printing Scala Case Classes Like A Tree

Tags: scala, printing, tree, proof

I am looking to build a tool that when an expression is input into it, it would produce a step by step evaluation proof and render it as a tree. I will also do the same thing for type checking tree.

Here are several examples of expressions and their equivalent ASTs:

- 1 + 1 + 1 = Plus(Plus(Num(1), Num(1)), Num(1))
- \x:int.x = Lambda(x,IntTy,Var(x))
- if 1 + x == 2 then 90 + 1 else 99 = IfThenElse(Eq(Plus(Num(1),Var(x)),Num(2)),Plus(Num(90),Num(1)),Num(99))

I want to output a nicely formatted step-by-step execution tree. Taking an example 1:

```
Num(1) | {eval res.}    Num(1) | {eval res.}
             ---------------------------------     --------------------
            Plus(Num(1), Num(1)) | {eval res.}    Num(1) | {eval res.}
         --------------------------------------------------------------
             Plus(Plus(Num(1), Num(1)), Num(1)) | {eval res.}
```

At each recursive step, I want to embed evaluation result into {eval res.}

In the future, I will also want to add capability of the user being able to do small-step evaluation. So, when we start at the bottom, when a button is clicked or something like that, the Plus(Num(1), Num(1)) | {eval res.} appears but not Num(1) | {eval res.} because left hand side recursion did not bottom out yet and it continues.

Here are a few examples of such proof trees:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcLTR.png

And type checking derivation: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RV2Bj.png

I want to print out a tree in a vertical manner like that. Having looked through related questions, I have not found anyone attempting this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is not a place where you can just ask for code, you have to try it first yourself. Please add a starting point in code to get a proper and quick answer to your question. See also stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Here is a JSFiddle I found online where it displays what I want. https://jsfiddle.net/vRb3P/   Hence, I am probably looking for building a Pretty Printer that will take in an AST and convert it into HTML. Am I on the right track?